# Cómo comunicarse con la alarma del sistema Sur-Gard 1

Tags: socket, tcpip

Necesito desarrollar un software que capte todas las alertas de alarma de un Sistema Sur-Gard 1. Por ahora desarrolle este servidor tcp en c# y funciona bien usando mi teléfono como cliente, pero no establece comunicación con la Sur-Gard. hice ping a la IP de la sur-gard y hay comunicación entre la sur-gard y el servidor ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Reconect:
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            Int32 port = 1025;

        server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port); 

        server.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"Waiting for a connection... ");

            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        server.Stop();
    }

    goto Reconect;
}

private static void ThreadProc(object obj)
{
    var client = (TcpClient)obj;
    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
    String cadena_obtenida = null;

    cadena_obtenida = null;

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    int i;

    try
    {
        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            cadena_obtenida = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            Console.WriteLine("Alerta recibida: {0}", cadena_obtenida);

            byte[] respuesta = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("El servidor ha recibido: " + cadena_obtenida + Environment.NewLine);

            stream.Write(respuesta, 0, respuesta.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    client.Close();
}
```

PD: He intentado colocar la ip que tiene la Sur-Gard en lugar del IPAddress.Any pero me salta el

> SocketException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10049): La dirección solicitada no es válida en este contexto.
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
>      at ConsoleServer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Juan W Asociados\source\repos\ConsoleServer\ConsoleServer\Program.cs:line 20